# How can you read a database port from application.properties with environment variables

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, environment-variables, port, environment

i am very new to Spring Boot and the application.properties. I have the problem, that i need to be very flexible with my database port, because i have two different databases. Therefore i want to read the port from a environment variable. I tried the following:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://project1:${db-password}@abc:12345/project
```

This code works fine, if my Database has the port 12345. But if i now try to read the port from an environment variable there is a problem.
I tried this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://project1:${db-password}@abc:${port}/project
```

The problem is the following: I am using k8 and Jenkins. The environment variable "port" is given to my program in my k8 and this works fine for "db-password", but not for the port. My Jenkins says:
"The connection string contains an invalid host 'abd:${port}'. The port '${port}' is not a valid, it must be an integer between 0 and 65535"

So now to my question:
How can i read a port as an environment variable, without getting this error?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: exec into shell, confirm that there is env variable you looking for, first.

Comment: You may only use variables that are provided by the environment. Because `db_password` works, we can assume it is provided. Per @oleg-butuzov, if you can shell into the container, you can enumerate all the environment variables (`env`) and see whether `${port}` is set. Just on a hunch (guess), if `${db_password}` works, have you tried ${db_port}`?

Comment: Did you look into this link: [Define environment variable container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/)?

Comment: yes already did that, the env variable is set, i checked it

Comment: if `ENV['port']` exists, check YOUR code, for example `$port}` (this is your example).

Comment: env port does not exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inject environment variable to the pods you can do the following:

#### Configmap

You can create `ConfigMap` and configure your pods to use it.

Steps required:

- Create `ConfigMap`
- Update/Create the deployment with ConfigMap
- Test it

#### Create ConfigMap

I provided simple `ConfigMap` below to store your variables:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: example-config
data:
  port: "12345"
```

To apply it and be able to use it invoke following command:

`$ kubectl create -f example-configmap.yaml`

The `ConfigMap` above will create the environment variable `port` with value of `12345`.

Check if `ConfigMap` was created successfully:

`$ kubectl get configmap`

Output should be like this:

```sh
NAME             DATA   AGE
example-config   1      21m
```

To get the detailed information you can check it with command:

`$ kubectl describe configmap example-config`

With output:

```
Name:         example-config
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Data
====
port:
----
12345
Events:  <none>
```

#### Update/Create the deployment with ConfigMap

I provided simple deployment with `ConfigMap` included:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: example-config
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Configuration responsible for using `ConfigMap`:

```
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: example-config
```

After that you need to run your deployment with command:

`$ kubectl create -f configmap-test.yaml`

And check if it's working:

`$ kubectl get pods`

With output:

```
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-deployment-84d6f58895-b4zvz   1/1     Running   0          23m
nginx-deployment-84d6f58895-dp4c7   1/1     Running   0          23m
```

#### Test it

To test if environment variable is working you need to get inside the pod and check for yourself.

To do that invoke the command:

`$ kubectl exec -it NAME_OF_POD -- /bin/bash`

Please provide the variable NAME_OF_POD with appropriate one for your case.

After successfully getting into container run:

`$ echo $port`

It should show:

```sh
root@nginx-deployment-84d6f58895-b4zvz:/# echo $port
12345
```

Now you can use your environment variables inside pods.